# Any way to increase sync period on Calendar?

Tags: sync, calendar, google-calendar

Is there any way to get my Galaxy S10 calendar to sync with entries that are more than 1 year in advance?

I have a calendar dedicated to keeping track of SSL certificate expiry (over 50 individual sites) so I have an entry for each site.

The problem is that some of my clients send me SSL certificates which have expiry dates 2 or 3 years in the future... so I update the existing entries with the new expiry date.

The result is that my phone leaves existing entries at their **previous** date, because they're now outside of the sync period.

Is there any way to increase the sync period... or is the simple answer to delete the old item and create a new one (instead of changing the date)?

Comment: What calendar data provider is used (local, Google, Exchange account, ...)? Have you tested a different calendar app to identify if this is an issue of the calendar app or the calendar data provider?

Comment: Yep, fair questions @Robert... it's Google calendar... not sure why I failed to highlight that originally.  And no, I haven't tried any different yet... I will do and get back to you